# SQLite .stats option - What do the performance values returned mean?

Tags: sqlite

SQLite has a 'dot' option in the command line interface of '.stats on|off'.

There is no information on this option on sqlite.org (that I could find). In fact I only found the option via the command line 'help' facility.

These are the output values from a sample query:

```
Memory Used:                         4601840 (max 4610656) bytes
Number of Outstanding Allocations:   3211 (max 14741)
Number of Pcache Overflow Bytes:     4509184 (max 4509184) bytes
Number of Scratch Overflow Bytes:    0 (max 6656) bytes
Largest Allocation:                  64000 bytes
Largest Pcache Allocation:           1172 bytes
Largest Scratch Allocation:          6640 bytes
Lookaside Slots Used:                6 (max 500)
Successful lookaside attempts:       27671
Lookaside failures due to size:      26080
Lookaside failures due to OOM:       24876
Pager Heap Usage:                    3417516 bytes
Page cache hits:                     2080
Page cache misses:                   640
Page cache writes:                   939
Schema Heap Usage:                   8024 bytes
Statement Heap/Lookaside Usage:      4624 bytes
Fullscan Steps:                      12926
Sort Operations:                     1
Autoindex Inserts:                   0
```

Does anyone know what these mean and how they can be used to analyse query performance?

Thank you.